# Bind a gridview to a table with some logic built into the table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and a datatable. Simple binding, right? But I want to color code some specific cells on my gridview based on the values of the cells. I know that I can do this on my row databound event, but that means I would have logic on the GUI side. Is there a way to bind to a datatable with the table already having some info about the formatting for the gridview cell? Ideally, I'd like to find way to pass something like a "value:color" combination for each cell so that on binding, the gridview would pick up the color for each cell.

Can this be done?

Comment: This sounds like an AttachedBehavior in WPF, but I'm not sure if asp.Net has anything like that. I would assume it does.

Comment: @Magus yes that's a pretty good way of describing it. ASP.NET tends to be a little more "raw" so it wouldn't surprise me if this wasn't possible. There might be a third-party gridview that does it but I don't want to use outside tools.

Answer (score 0):

From database

`Select  case  columnName when someValue then
'<span style="background-color:red">' + columnName + '<\span>'
Else columnName End as theColumn`

Then in gridview `ItemTemplate`

`<asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("theColumn")%>' runat="server">`

Comment: It looks like this would work, but isn't using `Eval` on the web considered on par with using `goto` in C#?